# How to execute commands in a child shell after some commands are exexuted in parent shell

Tags: linux, shell

I would like my commands(shell scripts) to be executed in the below scenario

I have commands to be executed

```
bef createTable xyz   [in Parent Shell]
bef useTable xyz      [spawns a subshell] 
bef refreshTable -latest [in the subshell]
exit   [in the subshell]
```

As an example I tried

```
/bin/bash -c 'bef useTable mrinal_bugs && exit'
```

But the exit did not execute

Comment: What is `bef` please?

Comment: It's a c executable which executes in a new subshell. The PID after and before running is different.